# Breeze and Entity Framework 7

Tags: breeze, entity-framework-core

The latest version of Breeze supports EF6. What does it take to migrate a Breeze project to use EF7?

As my project currently uses EFContextProvider, I think I have to move back and rely on DbContext instead. Does this mean I have to implement a replacement for EFContextProvider to use the latest version, or is there a way to get the current EFContextProvider version to use EF7's DbContext?

Comment: EF7 is an alpha. It's experimental at best. What's motivating your question?

Comment: The answer is probably "you can't use the current `EFContextProvider` with EF7's `DbContext`". You're welcome to try writing a custom `EF7ContextProvider`; you can start with the existing implementation which is on github.

Comment: Hi Ward. I am starting to explore the scope of work needed to migrate my project to vNext. It's for a hobby project that I hope to launch before the year ends.

Comment: Given my heavy dependency on Breeze, I might just have to wait until Breeze's officially supports EF7.

Comment: We will. And I too will be experimenting with vNext and Breeze ... soon I hope.

Comment: any news on this @Ward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF7 is a rewrite of Entity Framework. This means that there are many, many breaking changes. No existing EF6 components will work with EF7. Even the namespace of DbContext has changed. To read more about the decision to call it EF7 instead of giving it a new name, read [EF7 – v1 or v7?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/27/ef7-v1-or-v7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ward Bell, who owns Breeze, told me in Oct 2015 that they'd begun looking at EF 7 and understand where they'll need to get the metadata to do the code plumbing in Breeze that will be needed, but they didn't expect to start work on it before the end of 2015.  He did say that they fully intend to support ASP.NET 5 and EF 7, which are both in release candidate status and expected to be released Q1.  It wouldn't surprise me if a Breeze beta with EF 7 support appeared within a month.

Also, Bell did a session at DevSum2015 in which he addresses bridging the gap between Breeze and EF 7 in the meantime.  He has some examples of hand-written metadata as well as a look ahead in the [summary PDF of his slide deck](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi17vublqfKAhUCeCYKHUBDBEsQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cornerstone.se%2FSysSiteAssets%2Fdevsum15-presentationer%2Fward_bell_devsum2015_breeze.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFFRTIbEXrTvc9mcY4RK89NLsFqcg&sig2=EeZ1JxCBWtnGWqDvjSKONg).